# PHP errors on live site, works fine on localhost

Tags: php, warnings

So I have a site that uses a register/login system for users to create an account. I had the site working flawlessly on  my localhost with MAMP. However, I uploaded my site and database to a live server and I get errors. Below is the register page. When a user registers, it should take them to their account page, however the register page refreshed and they get the following errors:

> **Warning: session_start():** Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/disk4/2113278/www/lucasclarke.co.nf/webTechFinal/connections.php:16) in /srv/disk4/2113278/www/lucasclarke.co.nf/webTechFinal/Register.php on line 7
>
> **Warning: session_start():** Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /srv/disk4/2113278/www/lucasclarke.co.nf/webTechFinal/connections.php:16) in /srv/disk4/2113278/www/lucasclarke.co.nf/webTechFinal/Register.php on line 7
>
> **Warning: Cannot modify header information** - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/disk4/2113278/www/lucasclarke.co.nf/webTechFinal/connections.php:16) in /srv/disk4/2113278/www/lucasclarke.co.nf/webTechFinal/Register.php on line 16

Note that the info the user registers DOES go into my database correctly, but the website doesn't function as it did on my localhost. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php require 'connections.php'; ?>

<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['register'])) {

        session_start(); 

        $fname = $_POST['first_name'];
        $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pw = $_POST['password'];

        $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO user (Fname, Lname, Email, Password)Values('{$fname}', '{$lname}', '{$email}', '{$pw}')");

        header('Location: Login.php');
        }
?>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Notekeep</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>

            <div class="container">

                <h1 class="title">Register<img src="logo.png" id="logo"></h1> 

            <form action="" method="post" name="registerform" id="registerform">
                <div>
                    <input name="first_name" type="text" required="required"  id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input name="last_name" type="text" required="required"  id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input name="email" type="email" required="required"  id="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input name="password" type="password" required="required"  id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div>
                 <!--   <input name="password2" type="password" required="required"  id="password2" placeholder="Re-Enter Password"> -->
                </div>
            <div>
                    <input name="register" type="submit" class="button" id="register" value="Register">
                </div> 
            </form>

             <a class="link" href="Login.php">Login</a> 

          </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check line 16 of connections.php

Comment: The space after  `<?php require 'connections.php'; ?>` can not be there. The server is counting that space as output to the browser which throws an error. Remove the `?>` and the `<?php`

Comment: Also you should add `exit;` after your `header('Location: Login.php');`.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comments, your header should look like:

```
<?php
require('connections.php');
// Remove space, should be continuous
// I would personally start session here
session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $fname = $_POST['first_name'];
    $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pw = $_POST['password'];

    // !! This is injection-prone !!
    // You need to use bind parameters, this is unsafe
    $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO user (Fname, Lname, Email, Password)Values('{$fname}', '{$lname}', '{$email}', '{$pw}')");

    header('Location: Login.php');
    // Add here so the script stops execution
    exit;
}
?>
```

Also, take note of the SQL Injection that you are vulnerable to. You should use parameter binding:

```
function insertNewUser($array,$con)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $key               =    trim($key,':');
            $new[":{$key}"]    =    $value;
        }
        // I am assuming the use of PDO
        $query    =    $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (`Fname`,`Lname`,`Email`,`Password`) VALUES (:0,:1,:2,:3)");
        $query->execute($new);
    }
```

Use:

```
$data  =   array(
              $_POST['first_name'],
              $_POST['last_name'],
              $_POST['email'],
              $_POST['password']
           );

// Use the function
insertNewUser($data,$con);

header('Location: Login.php');
exit;
```

Lastly, you should not be inserting plaintext passwords into your database. You should be using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` *(or compatible library)*.